# Maven Eclipse plugin tries to download sources with double hyphen in the filename

Tags: eclipse, maven

Why would the Maven Eclipse plugin try to download source JARs with double hyphens in the file name? See the sample below: in all cases should the last bit of the URL be `spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE-sources.jar` (one hyphen) instead of `spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE--sources.jar` (two hyphens).

*I'm struggling to find out if this is due to a bug in the plugin, or Maven meta-data, or something else altogether.*

Here's a sample output of a Maven run, when running it with `mvn eclipse:eclipse -DdownloadSources=true  -DdownloadJavadocs=true -DforceRecheck=true`

```
Downloading: http://artifactory.local:8081/artifactory/repo/org/springframework/spring-web/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE--sources.jar
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.springframework:spring-web:java-source:-sources:3.0.5.RELEASE' in repository central (http://artifactory.local:8081/artifactory/repo)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-web/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE--sources.jar
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.springframework:spring-web:java-source:-sources:3.0.5.RELEASE' in repository default (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
Downloading: http://maven.springframework.org/release/org/springframework/spring-web/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE--sources.jar
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.springframework:spring-web:java-source:-sources:3.0.5.RELEASE' in repository spring-maven-release (http://maven.springframework.org/release)
Downloading: http://maven.springframework.org/milestone/org/springframework/spring-web/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE--sources.jar
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.springframework:spring-web:java-source:-sources:3.0.5.RELEASE' in repository spring-maven-milestone (http://maven.springframework.org/milestone)
Downloading: http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release/org/springframework/spring-web/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE--sources.jar
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.springframework:spring-web:java-source:-sources:3.0.5.RELEASE' in repository spring-roo-repository (http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release)
Downloading: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/springframework/spring-web/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE--sources.jar
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.springframework:spring-web:java-source:-sources:3.0.5.RELEASE' in repository JBoss Repo (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases)
Downloading: https://spring-roo-equals-roo-addon.googlecode.com/svn/maven-repository//org/springframework/spring-web/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE--sources.jar
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.springframework:spring-web:java-source:-sources:3.0.5.RELEASE' in repository googlecode.rooequals.repo (https://spring-roo-equals-roo-addon.googlecode.com/svn/maven-repository/)
Downloading: https://spring-roo-equals-roo-addon.googlecode.com/svn/maven-snapshot-repository//org/springframework/spring-web/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE--sources.jar
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.springframework:spring-web:java-source:-sources:3.0.5.RELEASE' in repository googlecode.rooequals.snapshotrepo (https://spring-roo-equals-roo-addon.googlecode.com/svn/maven-snapshot-repository/)
```

The plugin configuration:

```xml
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>  <!-- Note 2.8 does not work with AspectJ aspect path -->
    <configuration>
      <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
      <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
      <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
      <additionalBuildcommands>
        <buildCommand>
          <name>org.eclipse.ajdt.core.ajbuilder</name>
          <arguments>
            <aspectPath>org.springframework.aspects</aspectPath>
          </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
          <name>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</name>
        </buildCommand>
      </additionalBuildcommands>
      <additionalProjectnatures>
        <projectnature>org.eclipse.ajdt.ui.ajnature</projectnature>
        <projectnature>com.springsource.sts.roo.core.nature</projectnature>
        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
      </additionalProjectnatures>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

**UPDATE 1**

Maven version is:

```
> mvn -version
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 20:16:01+0100)
Java version: 1.6.0_37
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MacRoman
OS name: "mac os x" version: "10.6.8" arch: "x86_64" Family: "mac"
```

Comment: What's the version of maven?

Comment: What I also find suspicious is for example `org.springframework:spring-web:java-source:-sources:3.0.5.RELEASE` - what is the `java-source` part about? Isn't this superfluous? Never have seen this before.